# The requested url does not exist: 'https://rvm.io/src/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

When I run rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 this error happens:

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/christsongas/.rvm/archives
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
The requested url does not exist: 'https://rvm.io/src/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz'
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
There was an error, please check /Users/christsongas/.rvm/log//*.log
```

Of course I searched for that error on Google but didn't find any solution to this particular issue. Any idea why RVM is trying to download from non-existent URLs? Here's the output of rvm -v:

```
rvm 1.14.7 (version) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate markup to format that output, it's currently unreadable.

Comment: Ok tried to improve formatting. Not sure why some words are turned blue, please let me know if there are any specific steps I can take to further improve formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install recent stable version of `rvm` by running `rvm get stable` and then try again `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Mine version of `rvm: 1.25.27 (stable)`

Comment: Thank you, installing the latest stable version prompted me to run `rvm get stable` with the `--auto-dotfiles` flag to fix `RVM PATH line not found for Zsh` and also run `rvm cleanup all` after which I was able to successfully run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547`.